# Is this the right way to write a POST function in Python?

Tags: python, http, post

```
def URLRequest(url, params, method="POST"):
    h = Http()
    res, content = h.request(url, method, urllib.urlencode(params))
    r = {}
    r['res'] = res
    r['content'] = content
    return r
```

Suppose I want to POST `{"key":"value"}` to a url (REST). Is this function the right way to do it?

Comment: `urllib2.urlopen(url, data=urllib.urlencode(params))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works it is correct. You can make it shorter though:

```
def URLRequest(url, params, method="POST"):
    res, content = Http().request(url, method, urllib.urlencode(params))
    return {'res':res, 'content':content}
```